# How did heavy software in the early days managed to run on 4MB RAM computer?

Tags: performance, computer-science, computer-architecture, mac

It's no secret that in the early days of computers, they had only 1-4MB of RAM. I found an [article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/1991s-pc-technology-was-unbelievable/) stating you needed only 4MB of RAM to run Word, Excel and PowerPoint *simultaneously*. How was that possible, considering that nowadays you need at least 2GB, 1000x times more RAM to do the same thing? Sure, the new apps have more features, but at the core it's the same thing.

Comment: Decency and math helped a lot these 'ole days.

Comment: TextEdit in the first MacOS version was 1.5 kilobyte.

Comment: <grandpa voice> 4 Meg?  My first computer had 4K!  And we were happy to have that! </grandpa voice>

Comment: The author's entire article is pegged to March of 1991.  If you read a bit further down, you'll see that the multiple programs he was talking about were all DOS programs.  That's how.  *"In 1991 It was still a DOS world. And everyone knew it."*

Comment: Things were a lot simpler when buttons didn't need fading transparency gradients and smoothed fonts to render.

Comment: All together now: 4k, loooxury, all we 'ad were a 'ole in the road

Comment: Have you used [VisiCalc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisiCalc), the first spreadsheet program ever? Only text, only calculator features, running on Apple II.

Comment: 4 MB?  640 KB should have been enough: https://www.wired.com/1997/01/did-gates-really-say-640k-is-enough-for-anyone/

Comment: I don't know if there's a name for this phenomenon it but up until recently, software would grow to consume more RAM, CPU and disk as the hardware got better.  Software was constrained by these limits.  Software developers adjusted as the constraints were loosened.  Eventually we stopped worrying about it and software became more inefficient and bloated as hardware started outpacing the needs of desktop software.

Comment: I wrote a full featured graphical factory automation program with trending, alerting, recipes and thousands of digital and analog control points. It ran on a PC with 1MB RAM. I still work as a developer today, and fully understand what the answer to your question is, but it’s hard to summarize in a few paragraphs.

Comment: You might find [retrocomputing.se] intersting.

Comment: With careful writing and even more careful data handling.  I did CAD/CAM in 3mb back then.

Answer (score 10):

> How did heavy software in the early days managed to run on 4MB RAM computer?

It wasn't heavy.

That's it. There is no magic to it. Your question is based on a false premise.

I remember that my mom was using my dad's old IBM PC/AT with 512 KiByte of RAM and a 20 MiByte HDD well into the 1990s for word processing using Volkswriter and then later StarWriter. Considering that she was able to run a word processing program in 512 KiByte of RAM, I have no trouble believing the claim that you can run 3 programs in 8 times that.

The first word processors were written for computers whose RAM was measured in *bytes*, so why would it be surprising that you can run one in a million times that?

Comment: Yes, but requirements and user expectations were different as well. Volkswriyer (and earlier: Wordstar on less than 64KB RAM CP/M machines) did not have to offer true WYSIWIG and most fonts were fixed length (or if variable, only at the size supported by the printer, which was in charge of the rendering) :-)

Comment: @Christophe - Winword versions 1 and 2 were hardly different from Wordstar, at least not to that degree -- sure, they supported WYSIWYG, but that's mostly a by-product of running under Windows which provides all of the facilities required to do that, rather than CP/M which was a purely character-oriented system.  Windows added a little bit of overhead, but only a few hundred KB at most.  Winword version 2 ran perfectly happily on machines with less than 1MB, and version 1 was lighter still.

Comment: @Christophe since the purpose of word-processing was to print things, I think it's pretty fair to only let the user enter what the printer supported

Comment: @user253751 indeed. And some printers supported proportional spacing already, e.g. these wonderful [daisy wheel printers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_wheel_printing) that made your report look more like a book rather than these okd-looking fixed sized fonts ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Word for Windows was by today's standard a very small program. Its size is 13.07 MB on installer disks (1.44 MB each), which you can [download to check for yourself](https://winworldpc.com/download/15e28094-04c5-93c3-a9c5-b811c3a5c28f).

Microsoft Word 6.0 for Windows ran first on Windows 3.1 (released April 6, 1992) and looked nothing like Microsoft Word do today:

[image: Microsoft Word 6.0 for Windows]

Internet wasn't available, so updates to software where shipped in floppy disks. But it was a very good implementation of Word processing, and we still use the same keyboard shortcuts today as we did back then.

On MS Excel, when making advanced calculations in cells, my computer took a break. I could go to the next building and grab a coffee, and when I came back, the PC still wasn't done computing.

Computing power was scarce those days, and it wasn't always pleasing being an information worker back in 1992.

### UPDATE

As for memory consumption today(!), you'd need 150 MB to run MS Word, MS Excel and MS PowerPoint in the same time. That's a lot more than your 4 MB back in the days, but I have 16 GB available, so that's fine. What worries me though is that Google Chrome with this tab only open consumes 600 MB of RAM, telling me that it has nine ongoing processes. Time to look into that, but that's another story.

Comment: Not to mention Multiplan, the predecessor of Excel, which ran in character mode on MSDOS in the 80' on machines that had at maximum 640K of ram !

Comment: @Christophe My first PC experience comes from ABC 80, where I needed to take notes of my program after class, to type it in again the next class. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_80

Comment: wow Z80 ! That was already pretty advanced ;-)  I started on a 6502 based [SYM1](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?c=856) with 4 KB RAM, also with hand typed code.  Word processing was not really an option. But it could have been: [AppleWriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Writer) worked on a 6502 with a couple of more KB (32 I think).  Still a lot less than the grandiose 4MB of the question.

Comment: We still write windows programs that are 10 megabytes in size that work just fine, so this doesn't really answer anything.

Comment: No way you'd need 150mb back then, especially not on win 3.1. I remember running all those on win98 and I had 64M, and that was a respectable amount.

Comment: @whatsisname The update is for today. I just clarified- sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Even 4MB is plenty for most applications, even today, assume they're written in a halfway efficient manner.   Of course, most aren't...

Comment: @whatsisname - of course, Win 3.0 wouldn't even *recognise* 150MB of RAM.  Opinions vary on what the precise limit was (and MS doesn't seem to have any documentation online that goes back that far), but 64MB seems to be the common consensus.

Comment: I have a Multiplan floppy disk for my Commodore 64 , which only has 64 K of ram!